# what does '__getnewargs__' do in this code

Tags: python

```
class NavigableString(unicode, PageElement):

    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            return unicode.__new__(cls, value)
        return unicode.__new__(cls, value, DEFAULT_OUTPUT_ENCODING)

    def __getnewargs__(self):#this line
        return (NavigableString.__str__(self),)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = NavigableString('foop')
y = pickle.dumps(x)
z = pickle.loads(y)
print x, z
```

I.e.: [`__getnewargs__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) tells `pickle.dumps` to pickle `x` in such a way that a `pickle.loads` back from that string will use `NavigableString.__new__` with the proper argument.